# PHP and Facebook Integration

Tags: php, facebook

First, please forgive me asking the following as I'm sure it's been asked in some form or another a million times, but I checked related questions and couldn't find anything so...

When I last integrated with Facebook it was ASP .NET a long time ago. I know that the Facebook API changes constantly, and I'm wondering what the best way is these days to integrate in to Facebook from PHP.

I'm essentially looking to just download their name, friends list, after they auth the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook have released an official PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/.

In fact PHP is one of the two languages for which an official SDK exists, the other being JavaScript.